# How to get function object by name?

Tags: python, function

I do want to process a command with an argument specified by the user.
I thought about:

```
self.urlRegexFunc = "endswith"
self.urlRegex = ".mp3"
exec('b = attr[1].%s("%s")' % (self.urlRegexFunc, self.urlRegex)) # attr[1] is string
if b:
    pass # Do Something
```

But I get:

> SyntaxError: unqualified exec is not allowed in function 'start_a' it contains a nested function with free variables

What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [`getattr()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#getattr).